# How to verify that the given value is not in Table?

Tags: sql

I wanted to verify that particular name is there on either FIRST_NAME or LAST_NAME.

```
SELECT * FROM CONSUMER WHERE FIRST_NAME='<name>' OR LAST_NAME='<name>';
```

Checking that **count is zero**.

Is there any other way to write it in using NOT??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   consumer
WHERE  'name' NOT IN (first_name, last_name)
```